# No update notification when app-title changed

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app on the market for some time (7 month) that was labeled as "Beta" in the title.
Yesterday I published a new version and thought it's time to leave the beta state. Therefore I switched the app-title in the market backend and removed the "beta" tag.

The problem is: now, the users don't receive any update notification! If you search for the app in the market, the red update label is shown correctly. But in the "my apps" section, the update label and the notification is never shown. The user doesn't see that there's an update.

It didn't work on my two phones (both 2.2, I cleared the market cache) and it seems like, nearly all users continue to use the old version.

So, is this a known problem? Or was it just a temporary problem on my phone? Can anybody confirm this behaviour?

And, what can I do now? Switching the title back doesn't seem to help.

Thanks a lot

Marcus

Comment: Did you increment the version number in your manifest and upload the application again?  I don't think that you can force a user update without doing that.

Comment: Yes. I double checked it by decompiling the AndroidManifest.xml of the released apks. If the user searches for the app, the update information is correctly shown. But in the MyApps section, it remains up to date.

Comment: I would send an email to the support team for the market to get this resolved if you still haven't been able to let users update your app.

Comment: It seems like you cannot contact the market team. Sadly no one responds to anything. There is a group in the market help section but it's full of questions with no anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't change your package name?  (although the Market console should have thrown an error if you tried to upload and upgrade with a different pname)

Just change your label and version...